# Output Control won't take any value => UUU

Tags: vhdl

This is a mealy FSM. Since `A = 0`, `B = 0` and `mealy_state = STATE0`, output `Control` should be `000`. However it still holds the undefined value `UUU`.

Below you'll find the project module made on Xilinx. In the testbench I set both `A` and `B` to the value 0.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity MealyFSM is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : in  STD_LOGIC;             
           Control : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));
end MealyFSM;

architecture Behavioral of MealyFSM is

TYPE State IS (STATE0, STATE1, STATE2, STATE3, STATE4);
SIGNAL mealy_state : State ;

begin

process

begin

WAIT UNTIL CLK'EVENT AND CLK = '1' ; 
if RST = '1' then
mealy_state <= STATE0;

else
case mealy_state is 
WHEN STATE0 =>
if ((A = '0' and B = '0') or (A = '1' and B = '1')) then
mealy_state <= STATE0;
elsif (A = '0' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE4;
else 
mealy_state <=STATE1;
end if;


WHEN STATE1 =>
if (A = '0' and B = '0') or (A = '1' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE1;
elsif (A = '0' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE0;
else 
mealy_state <=STATE2;
end if;

WHEN STATE2 =>
if (A = '0' and B = '0') or (A = '1' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE2;
elsif (A = '0' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE1;
else 
mealy_state <=STATE3;
end if;

WHEN STATE3 =>
if (A = '0' and B = '0') or (A = '1' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE3;
elsif (A = '0' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE2;
else 
mealy_state <=STATE4;
end if;

WHEN STATE4 =>
if (A = '0' and B = '0') or (A = '1' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE4;
elsif (A = '0' and B = '1') then
mealy_state <= STATE3;
else 
mealy_state <=STATE0;
end if;

end case;
end if;
end process;


Control <= "000" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE0) AND ((A = '0' and B = '0') or(A = '1' and B = '1' ))  );
Control <= "000" WHEN( ((mealy_state = STATE1) AND (A = '1' and B = '0'))  );
Control <= "000" WHEN ((mealy_state = STATE4) AND (A = '0' and B = '1'));
Control <= "001" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE1) AND ((A = '0' and B = '0') or(A = '1' and B = '1' ))  );
Control <= "001" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE2) AND (A = '1' and B = '0')  );
Control <= "001" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE0) AND (A = '0' and B = '1')  );
Control <= "010" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE2) AND ((A = '0' and B = '0') or(A = '1' and B = '1' ))   );
Control <= "010" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE3) AND (A = '1' and B = '0')   );
Control <= "010" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE1) AND (A = '0' and B = '1')   );
Control <= "011" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE3) AND ((A = '0' and B = '0') or(A = '1' and B = '1' ))   );
Control <= "011" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE4) AND (A = '1' and B = '0')  );
Control <= "011" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE2) AND (A = '0' and B = '1')   );
Control <= "100" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE4) AND ((A = '0' and B = '0') or(A = '1' and B = '1' ))  );
Control <= "100" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE3) AND (A = '1' and B = '0')  );
Control <= "100" WHEN( (mealy_state = STATE0) AND (A = '0' and B = '1')  );

end Behavioral;
```

Testbench:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
 
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;
 
ENTITY MealyFSMtest IS
END MealyFSMtest;
 
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF MealyFSMtest IS 
 
    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 
    COMPONENT MealyFSM
    PORT(
         CLK : IN  std_logic;
         RST : IN  std_logic;
         A : IN  std_logic;
         B : IN  std_logic;
         Control : OUT  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    

   --Inputs
   signal CLK : std_logic := '0';
   signal RST : std_logic := '0';
   signal A : std_logic := '0';
   signal B : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal Control : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    
   -- Clock period definitions
   constant CLK_period : time := 10 ns;
 
BEGIN
 
    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: MealyFSM PORT MAP (
          CLK => CLK,
          RST => RST,
          A => A,
          B => B,
          Control => Control
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   CLK_process :process
   begin
        CLK <= '0';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
        CLK <= '1';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
   end process;
 

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
       RST <= '1';
    
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
      --wait for 100 ns;    

      wait for CLK_period*10;
        
        RST <= '0';
       A <= '0';
        B <= '0';

      wait for CLK_period;
      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: Due to missing indentation it is difficult to see which assignment to `Control` is under which `if` or `else`.

Comment: Why do you think that `mealy_state` is `STATE0`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I should have included the testbench in the question but it wouldnt let due to the presence of too much code. I've RST to be 1 for 10 clock periods, which makes mealy_state = state0 and after that i set RST to 0 and set A = 0 and B = 0 and expect a result in the value of control. I'll try to include the testbench.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You'll find the testbench on the posted question

Comment: That's why you are supposed to create a [mre].

Comment: Maybe you should wait for a few more clock periods after releasing RST?

Comment: @mkrieger1 just tried it. still nothing...

Comment: What do you get if you replace all assignments to Control to a single unconditional constant assignment?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It works. It gets the value after RST becomes 0, which I do find a little weird. I would expect it to be initialized from the beginning but maybe that's not how it works

Comment: Okay now go back to the previous code step by step and see when you start getting UUI again. Narrow it down like that until you have found what was missing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Is there a way i can check the valye of mealy_stake so I can make sure that that STATE0 is assigned as expected?

Comment: Yes, observe the waveforms in your simulator, or create console output. Just like you have observed the value of Control.

Comment: The assignments to Control after the last process statement in architecture Behavioral of MealyFSM are conditional concurrent signal assignment statements which are elaborated into process statements each with a driver for each element of Control. The value of Control is the resolution of each of it's elements drivers and 'U' resolved with anything else is 'U'.  All assignments to Control should be in the same process (or same conditional concurrent signal assignment statement).